# Import sage packages in sage -python virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, sage, ubuntu-22.04

I am trying to import sage python packages in a virtual environment. I built sage from the [source](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/). While executing the `python3` executable (inside `$SAGE_LOCAL/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.10/bin`) the sage can be imported along with its other packages like `sage.all`. I tried exporting the `$PATH` of `$SAGE_LOCAL/bin` in `.bashrc` but it didn't solve the problem.

I created a virtual environment with sage-python as `sage-python3 -m venv test_venv`. The executable inside the virtual environment: `test_venv/bin/python3` has symbolic link to the `$SAGE_LOCAL/var/lib/sage/venv-python3.10/bin/python3` but when importing `sage.all` it throws: `No module named 'sage.all'`.

How can I create a sage virtual environment and import sage python packages? Sage doesn't have PiPy implementation.

Comment: i solved this issue myself and i have updated the Readme.md of the official [Sage repo](https://github.com/sagemath/sage#alternative-installation-using-pypi).